# mod_rewrite not matching last match

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Input url: `application.local/v2/en-us/login`

Expected output url: `application.local/app_dev.php/en-us/login`

The only difference here is we're replacing `/v2/` with `/app_dev.php`. Here is my rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/(v2)?/(([A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+)|_(.*)+)?/(.*)+?$ /app_dev.php/$2/$3 [R,L]
```

In order, my logic goes:

- Match `/v2/` (this goes into `$1`) *or _profiler, _wdt etc that Symfony uses*
- Match the locale (this goes into `$2`)
- Match the thing after, in this case: `login` (this goes in `$3`)

However, `$3` doesn't contain `login` as I expect it to, instead I get:

```
application.local/app_dev.php/en-us/en-us
```

Although I have the replacement for `/v2/` and `/app_dev.php` working, I think I'm messing up the match between `$2` and `$3` somewhere for `login`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^/(v2)?/(([A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+)|_(.*)+)?/(.*)+?$
  ||||  ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  ||||
  1111  2|||||||||||||||||||||22||||22  5555
         333333333333333333333  4444
```

You have inner groups that count, I added the numbers so you can easily see it.

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^/(v2)?/(([A-Za-z]+-[A-Za-z]+)|_(.*)+)?/(.*)+?$ /app_dev.php/$2/$5 [R,L]
```

Instead of using the complicated regex, you could just route everything.

```
RewriteRule ^/v2/(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, pointing out the groupings and how they worked *really* helped.